# How to validate JSON's specific element against DB data in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to perform validation of JSON response against DB data.
For example I have a student table with column as "StudentID" , "StudentName" and "StudentAddress"
and In JSON response we have element as "StudentNumber", "StuName" and "StuAddress" (Name is different in both JSON and DB)

Question 1: How can I compare entire JSON against the DB data to match it in JMeter.

Question 2: If I want to perform validation like if in Database "StudentID"=1 then in JSON response "StudentNumber" should be equal to "A". How can I validate it in JMeter in a single script

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare entire JSON to the result of the database query which returns more than 1 row - the only option is going for [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and implementing your pass/fail criteria in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/).

- [Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so it can parse the response as JSON and convert it to maps/lists/values
- Groovy can iterate the [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object containing the query results, see [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) for more details

If you want to compare individual entries:

- In the [JDBC Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) specify variable name to store the value from the database
- Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to store the value from JSON
- Compare 2 variables using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample code used within a JSR223 element to process JSON response

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

try{
    def responseJSON = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
    
    if(responseJSON) {
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseJSON)
        def itemCount = object['items']['id'].size()
        
        log.info("Items $itemCount")        
        for (i in 0..<itemCount){
            log.info("Student Number ${object['items']['id'][i]}")
            log.info("Student Name ${object['items']['studentName'][i]}")
            log.info("Address ${object['items']['address'][i]}")
        }
    
}catch (anything){
    log.info("Error ")
}
```

Groovy has support for working with JSON. [Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html).